# Alternative for namespaces in xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xsd

I have a web-service which gives a xml feed for number of clients of us, our clients consumes the xml in different types of devices. In our XML we have some namespaces also. But one of our clients can't detect namespaces because of some limitation at their end. But I can't provide a new xml for him as well. 
Please suggest me something so that I can satisfy the needs of namespaces without using that, so that i can change my xml to be usable by all of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to how C programmers emulate namespaces with function name prefixes as in `http_get()` and `http_post()` vs the C++ way with namespaces as in `http::get()` and `http::post()`, you could output your XML with elements like `<ns_elem>` instead of `<ns:elem>`.

Comment: Thnx @benhoyt. I have simply applied a string replace mechanism to replace all the `:` sign with  `_` and I am able to parse it now in the client side now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply applied a string replace mechanism to replace all the `:` sign with `_` and I am able to parse it now in the client side now.

Comment: Interesting -- are you doing the string replace of `:` with `_` in the entire XML document? That's very dangerous, of course, because attributes and text content may well have colons in them. Perhaps there's some way to only replace in tag names.

Comment: If you have complete control over the source XML output, simple string replacement could work for you in your situation. That said, this simplistic approach could ultimately prove fragile.

Answer (score 2):

```
But one of our clients can't detect namespaces because of some limitation at their end.
```

One would need to know more about what the limitation is before going to great efforts to work around it. Since namespace-aware XML parsers are pretty ubiquitous, it must be a very strange environment they are working in, and perhaps the ability to handle namespaces is not its only restriction?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to automatically transform your xml format which contains the namespace into another one using a stylesheet ([XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) / `xsltproc`), stripping off the namespace. The stylesheet in this case would be very simple (only a few lines) and easy to maintain. The resulting document is just a *copy* of the old without the namespace, so it would basically stay the same.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that more than one namespace may be present.

Comment: I think he was looking for a deterministic hack rather than a permanent solution, but you're absolutely right. Namespaces are the core of XML, making a hole universe of other markups possible, which also implies they're used in parallel.